# how to make a split screen in android application?

Tags: java, android, layout

I am working on a game which has multiplayer(on same device) and I need to have a split screen for player 1 and 2. Player one will be on bottom while player 2 is on top. And player 2's side should be flipped so that both players and screens are facing each other.  I have both layouts set but I don't know how to get the top side flipped. I used two LinearLayouts which are are wrapped with a RelativeLayout.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Don't know how to flip the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
android:rotation="180"
```

in you xml file on your LinearLayout that you want to flip.